# Screen resolution Insufficient

Tags: windows-8, updates, resolution

I downloaded the Windows 8 from Microsoft, which tested my hardware before allowing download.

I fail to understand why it did not advise me that my resolution is not compatible.

The installation also interchanged my <kbd>@</kbd> key (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>)  with my <kbd>"</kbd> key.

Comment: What is your hardware? What kind of monitor? or are we talking about a netbook?  Also: your second part should be a second question.

Answer (score 1):

Is your resolution lower than 1024 x 768? That's the minimum required to run Modern-UI apps.

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan already wrote, th eminimum screen resolution for windows 8 is 1024x768. See [this link for the reason](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx).

As for the keyboard: Check your locale settings. Several languages have their own locale setting and some of them have quotes in the normal place of the @. If you select such a localized keyboard as input source then you get precisely what you describe.

As for your third point: I can only agree. They should at least add a warning that it will fail on your resolution. This seems a point which Microsoft can improve.

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution**

This sounds like a driver problem and a quick fix is to trick Windows 8 into thinking your resolution is higher. There is a complete guide [here](http://liliputing.com/2011/09/how-to-enable-windows-8-metro-style-apps-on-an-older-netbook.html).

1. Open the registry  editor <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type in regedit
2. Find the following key `Display1_DownScalingSupported`. The location is different for every driver
3. Set the value to 1 for every time the key was found
4. Reboot
5. Now you can change the resolution to higher values

In your case it is not really clear what happened.  You installed Windows 8 and then Windows 8 told you that your resolution was incompatible?

**Keyboard**

These sound like the differences between regional keyboard layouts. You should verify what your keyboard layout is set to. Detailed instructions can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/121169/how-to-change-your-keyboard-layout-in-windows-8/). The cause of the problem maybe that the method says 'UK' when it should say 'US'.
[image]
[image]